# Open GL version 2.1 instead of 4.1 in Mac OS 10.15

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, glut

I'm new to Mac, so I'm not very conversant with the get arounds with this OS.

I wrote a simple Open GL program in Xcode and it ran without issues. However, when I checked the versions using the following code

```
cout<<glGetString(GL_VENDOR)<<endl;
cout<<glGetString(GL_RENDERER)<<endl;
cout<<glGetString(GL_VERSION)<<endl;
cout<<glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION)<<endl;
```

Initialization Code

```
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
glutInitWindowSize(400, 400);
glutCreateWindow("First Test");
initRendering();
glutDisplayFunc(drawScene);
glutKeyboardFunc(handleKeypress);
glutReshapeFunc(handleResize);
glutMainLoop();
```

I get the following output

```
ATI Technologies Inc.
AMD Radeon Pro 5300M OpenGL Engine
2.1 ATI-3.10.15
1.20
```

From forums elsewhere I have read that Mac OS 10.15 supports Open GL version 4.1 and the Graphics card here can certainly support higher versions too.

**So my questions are as follows:**

1. Why is it showing 2.1 on my machine
2. How to fix this? Is there a code that I can type into fix the issue or more software needs to be installed?

Any direction would be great.

Thanks

Comment: How do you request the context? Do you request a specific version?

Comment: macOS supports only *Core Profile* of OpenGL 3+ versions - that's all. You need requesting `NSOpenGLPFAOpenGLProfile, NSOpenGLProfileVersion3_2Core` while creating OpenGL context.

Comment: @BDL updated. I don't have a specific version but I need to know how to do this to start with. If I can get to 4.1 that would be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GLUT is ancient and doesn't support common macOS features such as HiDPI or mouse scrolling. You probably want to look into using the GLFW library instead ([see here for what you need to do for a 4.1 context](https://www.glfw.org/faq.html#41---how-do-i-create-an-opengl-30-context)).

However if you really want to use GLUT, you need to add

```c
glutInitContextVersion(4, 1);
glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);
```

after `glutInit`.

Answer (score 1):

> Edit: the answer was posted before I know he's using glut, also I recommend GLFW for Modern OpenGL 4.1+

I think you should define the version and create the context first, using some libraries like GLFW and set the OpenGL profile intended to use. also use GLEW/GLAD libraries for GL extensions management.
In case you are using GLFW and GLEW you can add this code to define a version and create a context and a window. then check the version again.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h> 
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

using namespace std;
int main() 
{
   // Initialize GLFW
   glfwInit();

   // Define version and compatibility settings
   glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3); //ver
   glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2); 
   glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE,GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
   glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); // for MAC ONLY
   glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

   // Create OpenGL window and context
   GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "OpenGL", NULL, NULL);
   glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

   // Check for window creation failure
   if (!window) 
   {
       // Terminate GLFW
       glfwTerminate();
       return 0; 
   }

   // Initialize GLEW
   glewExperimental = GL_TRUE; glewInit();

   // your code
   cout<<glGetString(GL_VENDOR)<<endl;
   cout<<glGetString(GL_RENDERER)<<endl;
   cout<<glGetString(GL_VERSION)<<endl;
   cout<<glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION)<<endl;


   // Event loop
   while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) 
   {
       // Clear the screen to black
       glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
       glfwSwapBuffers(window);
       glfwPollEvents(); 
   }

   // Terminate GLFW
   glfwTerminate(); return 0;
}
```

If you don't have GLFW and GLEW already installed, you can check this tutorial to install them for MacOS : https://riptutorial.com/opengl/example/21105/setup-modern-opengl-4-1-on-macos--xcode--glfw-and-glew- or check this one: https://giovanni.codes/opengl-setup-in-macos/

> in case it does not work and still showing 2.1 try to go to the "Energy Saver" in the system settings and deselect the "Automatic graphics switching".

Comment: I use glut not glfw. Not sure of the changes in both.

Comment: I see that after you just edited it, I think if you intend to use Modern OpenGL 4.1+ use GLFW will be better. but in your case now try to go to the "Energy Saver" in the system settings and deselect the "Automatic graphics switching". .and check again